# Manipulate an element in cypress using text in the row

Tags: typescript, automation, cypress

How can I access from the code below 'switch__obj' using content from row?

For example I want to manipulate with check()/uncheck() that 'switch__obj', which is a slider button, but find it with the help of content, kind of like `cy.get('row').contains('Text wherewith find that').find('.switch__obj').uncheck({force:true})...` ?

I tried with parent(), parents(), find(), children() but I couldn't find it.

```
 <div _ngcontent-iil-c662="" class="row">
       <div _ngcontent-iil-c662="" class="col-10"><label _ngcontent-iil-c662="" for="chkOnlineBooking" class="label-bold">Allow patients to book appointments online</label></div>
       <div _ngcontent-iil-c662="" class="col-2">
          <div _ngcontent-iil-c662="" class="pull-right switch switch-small">
             <div _ngcontent-iil-c662="" class="col-auto"><label _ngcontent-iil-c662="" class="o-switch"><input _ngcontent-iil-c662="" type="checkbox" ng-reflect-model="true" ng-reflect-is-disabled="false" ng-reflect-options="[object Object]" class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty"><span _ngcontent-iil-c662="" data-off="No" data-on="Yes" class="switch__obj"></span></label><label _ngcontent-iil-c662="" for="chkOnlineBooking"></label></div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I hope I have given all the necessary information. Thank you!

Note: I used this code and working, but i want to find it based on text, and not with eq() option `cy.get('.switch__obj').eq(0).parent().find('input').uncheck({force:true})`

Answer (score 1):

Identify the row with correct text using `contains()`, specifying `.row` as the element to return.

Then just `.find()` the input directly in that row.

```js
cy.get('.row', 'Allow patients to book appointments online')
  .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
  .check()
```

You can actually omit `[type="checkbox"]`, but it reads better when later reviewing your test - you know that `.check()` is the correct action, not `.click()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something likle this:

```js
cy.contains('div', 'Allow patients to book appointments online')
  .parent() //Moves to parent div row
  .within(() => { //scopes the commands within the above div row
    cy.get('.switch__obj').click()
  })
```

If you want to use the `check` command, you can do this:

```js
cy.contains('div', 'Allow patients to book appointments online')
  .parent() //Moves to parent div row
  .within(() => { //scopes the commands within the above div row
    cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]').check()
  })
```

Comment: I think this gets them closer, but the `.switch__obj` element is a `span`, so they'll probably have to get the sibling `input` element to actually see the `click()` work.

Comment: With your code, i have this error (i used uncheck() / check() and not click() ):  "cy.uncheck() can only be called on :checkbox. Your subject is a: <span _ngcontent-lgl-c662="" data-off="No" data-on="Yes" class="switch__obj"></span>"

Comment: You can use the check command with the following selector `cy.get('input[type="checkbox"]').check()`.